# Signal is connected to following multiple drivers

Tags: verilog, xilinx, ise

[image]

This is the top module combining the Circular Shift Register, Multiplexer and Adder.

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps
module top(
input CLK,
input [9:0] imgPixel,
output [15:0] WORD_OUT
);

integer j;
reg imgPixBit;
wire [15:0] word;

reg [3:0] counter;
wire select;
wire [15:0] reg_mx0 = 16'd0,reg_mx1= 16'd0,reg_mx2= 16'd0,reg_add0= 16'd0;

// Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
cir_shift_reg_v csr (
    .CLK(CLK), 
    .WORD_OUT(word)
);

initial
begin
    j=4'd0;
    counter = 4'd0;
end

always @(posedge CLK)
begin
    if (j<10) 
    begin
        imgPixBit = imgPixel[j];        
        j = j + 1;
        counter = counter + 1;
    end
    else
    begin
        j = 4'd0;
        counter = 4'd0;
    end 
end

mux mx0 (
    .CLK(CLK),
    .WORD_IN1(word),
    .WORD_IN2(16'd0),
    .SELECT_BIT_IN(imgPixBit),
    .WORD_OUT(reg_mx0)
);  

control crtl0 (
    .CLK(CLK),
    .counter(counter),
    .condition(4'd0),
    .SELECT_BIT_OUT(select_mx1)
);

mux mx1 (
    .CLK(CLK),
    .WORD_IN1(reg_add0),
    .WORD_IN2(16'd0),
    .SELECT_BIT_IN(select_mx1),
    .WORD_OUT(reg_mx1)
);

adder add0 (
    .CLK(CLK),
    .WORD_IN1(reg_mx0),
    .WORD_IN2(reg_mx1),
    .WORD_OUT(reg_add0)
);  

    control crtl1 (
    .CLK(CLK),
    .counter(counter),
    .condition(4'd9),
    .SELECT_BIT_OUT(select_mx2)
);

mux mx2 (
    .CLK(CLK),
    .WORD_IN1(reg_add0),
    .WORD_IN2(reg_mx2),
    .SELECT_BIT_IN(select_mx2),
    .WORD_OUT(reg_mx2)
);  

assign WORD_OUT = reg_mx2;
endmodule
```

Circular Shift Register Module

```
module cir_shift_reg_v(
input CLK,
output reg [15:0] WORD_OUT
);

parameter initialValue = {16'h0,16'h1,16'h2,16'h3,16'h4,16'h5,16'h6,16'h7,16'h8,16'h9}; 
//This works because concatenation makes it a 160bit wide value.

reg [15:0] wordShiftReg[9:0];
integer i;

initial begin
for (i=0;i<10;i=i+1) 
 begin
    wordShiftReg[i] = initialValue[((9-i)*16)+:16];
end
end

always @(posedge CLK)
begin
WORD_OUT <= wordShiftReg[0]; 
for (i=0;i<9;i=i+1) begin
    wordShiftReg[i] <= wordShiftReg[i+1];
end
wordShiftReg[9] <= WORD_OUT;    
end
endmodule
```

Mux module

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps
module mux(
input CLK,
input [15:0] WORD_IN1,
input [15:0] WORD_IN2,
input SELECT_BIT_IN,
output reg [15:0] WORD_OUT
);

always @(posedge CLK)
    WORD_OUT = (SELECT_BIT_IN) ? WORD_IN1 : WORD_IN2;
endmodule
```

Control Module

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps
module control(
input CLK,
input [3:0] counter,
input [3:0] condition,
output reg SELECT_BIT_OUT
);

always @(posedge CLK)
    SELECT_BIT_OUT = (counter==condition) ? 1 : 0;

endmodule
```

Adder Module

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps
module adder(
input CLK,
input [15:0] WORD_IN1,
input [15:0] WORD_IN2,
output reg [15:0] WORD_OUT
);

always @(posedge CLK)
    WORD_OUT = WORD_IN1 + WORD_IN2;

endmodule
```

The Circular shift register works perfectly but I am not sure about the other modules.

The error is shown with reg_mx0, reg_mx1 during Adder module instantiation.

Can someone please help me out? Any optimization in the code is most welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you declared the signals at the top of the main file, you also gave them constant values. Remove the assignments in the `wire` statement.

Comment: Thanks Dave, but I am still getting a lot of warnings like..

`WARNING:Xst:1896 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch <csr/wordShiftReg_0_13> has a constant value of 0 in block <top>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.`
`WARNING:Xst:1895 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch <csr/WORD_OUT_6> .......`
`WARNING:Xst:2677 - Node <mx1/WORD_OUT_4> of sequential type is unconnected in block <top>.`
`WARNING:Xst:2677 - Node <add0/WORD_OUT_4> of sequential type is unconnected in block <top>.`

Comment: Same warnings are coming for <mx0/WORD_OUT>, <mx1/WORD_OUT>, <mx2/WORD_OUT>, <add0/WORD_OUT>,  <j> and <csr/wordShiftReg>.

Comment: You haven't included the source for `cir_shift_reg_v`in your question, so I can't comment on that, other than to say that it doesn't appear to have a reset input, which is probably a bad idea. It looks like the synthesis tool is assuming that its outputs are constant. This leads to a lot of constants propagating throughout the design, and the tool is telling you that a lot of your logic gets optimized away as a result.

Comment: Thanks for the input @Dave Tweed, I have added the Circular shift register module to the post. I will also integrate the reset input. But I am also not getting the correct output on simulating, which I don't think would be rectified with reset input. Can you point out any other mistakes?

Comment: Wait, in your original post, you said "the circular shift register works perfectly". Which is it? In any case, it has a 16-bit output, but 12 of those bits are always zero. This is why most of your logic is getting trimmed away in synthesis.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the 12 bits. Anyways even with or without the warning the output is not correct. Can you help me find any logical error that I might have made.